# SQLite data input in ion list

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sqlite, ionic-framework

I have some problem with data input in ion-list. I read some in StackOverflow but my problem doesn't solved. I would like that data from DB input in items on my screen. I am new in AngularJS and Ionic, please help! I am will very grateful if you help solve my problem! 
P.S. Sorry for my English.

 
**litedb.js**

```js
var db = null;

angular.module('starter.litedb', ['ngCordova'])

// db controller
.controller("LitedbCtrl", function($scope,$cordovaSQLite,$ionicPopup){
    $scope.insert = function(cardnum, datat, eventt, sum, category, total) {
      var query = "INSERT INTO smsdata (cardnum, datat, eventt, sum, category, total) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
      $cordovaSQLite.execute(db,query, [cardnum, datat, eventt, sum, category, total]).then(function(result){
        console.log("INSERT ID ->" + result.insertId);
      }, function(error){
        console.log(error);
      })
    }
        $scope.selectAll = function(){
        var alldataSMS = [];
      var query = "SELECT * FROM smsdata";
      $cordovaSQLite.execute(db,query,[]).then(function(result){
          if(result.rows.length>0){
            console.log("SELECTED ->" + result.rows.item(0).id + " " +
             result.rows.item(0).category);
             for (var i = 0; i < result.rows.length; i++) {
// cardnum, datat,  eventt, sum, category, total  
              alldataSMS.push({
               id: result.rows.item(i).id,
               cardnum: result.rows.item(i).cardnum,
               datat: result.rows.item(i).datat,
               eventt: result.rows.item(i).eventt,
               sum: result.rows.item(i).sum,
               category: result.rows.item(i).category,
               total: result.rows.item(i).total
              })
             }
              $scope.$apply();
          } else {
            console.log("NO ROWS EXIST");
          }
      
      }, function(error){
          console.log(error);
      })
    }

})
```

```html
<ion-view view-title="History">
<ion-nav-buttons side="right"> 
     <button class="button button-icon ion-plus"> </button>
</ion-nav-buttons> 
<ion-pane ng-controller="LitedbCtrl">
  <ion-content >
    <button class="button" ng-click="selectAll()">SelectALL</button>
    <ion-list>
     <ion-item ng-repeat="fsdata in alldataSMS">
     <h3>{{fsdata.eventt}}</h3>
     {{fsdata.datat}}
     {{fsdata.sum}}
     {{fsdata.category}}
     {{fsdata.total}}
     </ion-item> 
    </ion-list>
   
  </ion-content>
  </ion-pane>
</ion-view>
```

**app.js**

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers','starter.chart',
  'starter.litedb'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform, $cordovaSQLite ) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);

    }
    if (window.StatusBar) {
      // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
    // localDB.sync(remoteDB, {live: true});
    db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB({name: "app.db", location: 'default'});
   $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS smsdata (id integer primary key, cardnum text, datat text, eventt text, sum text, category text, total text)");
  });
})
```

And console log

[image]

Comment: It looks like you're just missing ng-app="starter" in your html.

Comment: @MikeFeltman I try to add ng-app="starter" in my history.html first times into <ion-view view-title="History" ng-app="starter" > and second into <ion-pane ng-controller="LitedbCtrl" ng-app="starter"> compile and rup application but it is doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem, it was my folt i use another method razer into documentation. Read [Github plugin repo](https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage)
. and my **litedb.js**

```js
var db = null;

angular.module('starter.litedb', ['ionic','ngCordova'])

// db controller
.controller("LitedbCtrl", function($scope, $ionicPlatform, $cordovaSQLite){

    var db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({ name: 'my.db', location: 'default' }, function () {
    db.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS smsdata (id integer primary key, cardnum text, datat text, eventt text, sum text, category text, total text)");
}, function (error) {
    console.log('Open database ERROR: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
});

function addItem(cardnum, datat, eventt, sum, category, total) {

    db.transaction(function (tx) {

        var query = "INSERT INTO smsdata (cardnum, datat, eventt, sum, category, total) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

        tx.executeSql(query, [cardnum, datat, eventt, sum, category, total], function(tx, res) {
            console.log("insertId: " + res.insertId);
            console.log("rowsAffected: " + res.rowsAffected);
        },
        function(tx, error) {
            console.log('INSERT error: ' + error.message);
        });
    }, function(error) {
        console.log('transaction error: ' + error.message);
    }, function() {
        console.log('transaction ok');
    });
}
// addItem('1452', '13.02.2016', 'покупка', '400' ,'Продукты', '800');
// addItem('1452', '15.02.2016', 'зачесление', '1100' ,'Банкомат', '1900');
// addItem('1452', '19.02.2016', 'покупка', '75' ,'Продукты', '1825');
// addItem('1452', '20.02.2016', 'покупка', '290' ,'Здоровье', '1535');
// addItem('1452', '25.02.2016', 'покупка', '950' ,'Развлечения', '585');
// addItem('1452', '29.02.2016', 'покупка', '49' ,'Продукты', '536');

function selAll(){

 $scope.alldataSMS = [];

 db.executeSql("SELECT * FROM smsdata", [], function (result) {
   for(var x = 0; x < result.rows.length; x++) {
  // console.log('cardnum: ' + result.rows.item(x).cardnum +
  //  ' Data: ' + result.rows.item(x).datat +
  //   ' Event: ' + result.rows.item(x).eventt +
  //   ' Sum: ' + result.rows.item(x).sum + 
  //   ' category: ' + result.rows.item(x).category +
  //   ' total: ' + result.rows.item(x).total);

   $scope.alldataSMS.push({id:result.rows.item(x).id,
               cardnum:result.rows.item(x).cardnum,
               datat:result.rows.item(x).datat,
               eventt:result.rows.item(x).eventt,
               sum:result.rows.item(x).sum,
               category:result.rows.item(x).category,
               total:result.rows.item(x).total});
  };
}, function(error) {
  console.log('SELECT error: ' + error.message);
});
}

selAll();

function closeDB() {
    db.close(function () {
        console.log("DB closed!");
    }, function (error) {
        console.log("Error closing DB:" + error.message);
    });
}

});
```